# The best way to read formatted data from NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have one NSString object and I'm trying to read its content. I know the format of its content is as follows:

```
"v %f %f %f\n"
```

One way to do this is to get the c-style string of the NSString object and then use the method:

```
sscanf(cstring,"v %f %f %f\n");
```

Are there any other ways? My solution is too "C-style".

## Edit:

The expected format of the NSString is

```
"v %f %f %f\n"
```

But it may be in other format if the data is not correct.

Comment: NSScanner is probably your best option here. It can get a little bit on the verbose side, but it probably will give you the most robustness.

Comment: What's wrong with good ol' C style? By the way, I second Richards statement about NSScanner.

Comment: Please modify your question to state you want the "best" way to read data from a string and also remove your "sample" format since you say it might not be formatted that way.

Comment: I'm new to objective-c. Although I know objective-c is super set of c, I often wonder whether there's a substitute for specific method of c. Thanks @OralB, I'm looking into NSScanner.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSString methods like this:

```
NSArray *vals = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
float f1 = [vals[1] floatValue];
float f2 = [vals[2] floatValue];
float f3 = [vals[3] floatValue];
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that. It will crash very ungracefully if the data ever appears in another format (separated by tabs instead of spaces), as opposed to the `sscanf` or `NSScanner` methods.

Comment: This may be a possible solution, thank you @kailoon. But I agree with Richard J. Ross III that if the data do not appear in the format as I  expected, the program may crash.

Comment: Your question was were there any others ways to get the data from the string you provided, not what is the best way to get any data from any type of formatted string, and yes I understand it is not rebust, again, that was not the question.

Comment: I'm sorry @kailoon, my bad. I've edited the question as you suggested.